# I want to ask the user through a bat file true or false, with true continuing through the bat file and false closing it + color change

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

First, I am new to this site and am not talking English as my primary languace so sorry about my gramatic.
I am trying to make a simple .bat script (i think script) to impress my friends and learn some basics about this type of programming.

SO,

I began it using the echo off so that the /user thing wont appear.
I selected the color, but i want to use another one for some lines and then change back to the original. ( **This is the first problem i need help with**)
**The second problem** i encountered is that i want to have the command line ask true(T) or False(F) (with the letters t and f being what i would have to write to chose that option) , true making the command prompt continue throught the lines i will add later down, and false exiting the window.

Here i inserted a part of the code i allready made.

EXTRA INFO: 
(WORDS) mean that i will write something there to appear

what i wrote ( ) are some notes for the answer, and wont appear in the script

```
@echo off
color 0A
echo  (I WILL WRITE SOME THINGS HERE TO APPEAR) 
pause
echo (WORDS)
echo (WORDS) 
echo (WORDS)
color 0C 
echo (COLORED WORDS IN 0C)
color 0A (CHANGE THE COLOR FOR THE NEXT LINES BACK)
echo (WORDS)
echo (WORDS)
(HERE I WANT THE TRUE OR FALSE LINES)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice command is what you are looking for (Although there are other ways to do this).

Try adding this to your batch script to see how it works:

```
@echo off

set /p continue= choice /c tf /m "Complete Action (T)rue, (F)alse"
if '%continue%' == 'f' exit
if '%continue%' == 't' echo "Continuing on"

pause
```

And for more options or information, you can type `choice /?` into a command prompt.

The break down (edited)

Call choice with the following options:
/c is choices, tf is the characters t and f, of course you could also do abcde and have a, b, c, d, e.

/m is for your message and it must be wrapped in " ".

Choice will auto append a question a mark to the question.
Edited

Comment: It adds the true or false but the script continues no matter witch i chose.

Comment: i wrote in the post that true should just continue the script and false should close the window

Comment: How can i set false option to do close the window ( exit command) ?

Comment: I found a mistake in your answer that held it from working.... no % before the first continue

Comment: Few things: Try not have a conversation in comments: If it worked, please vote and/ or accept: If there are more questions then please ask a new question. This is a Q&A site not a forum.

Comment: Its not a forum i know but u didnt answered the other thing i asked int the question...

Comment: I tried using color 0C before that line but it stays to 0A

Comment: Sounds like another question to debug your script then, works fine for me anywhere through the script.

Comment: Thanks anyway, and if you can can you give an color change example?